# Pass object to Parent component from Child. I want to pass object from child to parent component but i does not work. how i should correct to do this?

Tags: lightning-web-components

Child html

```
<!-- sldsValidatorIgnore -->
<template>
   <div style="height: 185px;">
      <lightning-datatable
              key-field="ID"
              data={data}
              columns={columns}
              onsave={handleSave}>               
      </lightning-datatable>
  </div> 
  <lightning-button variant="brand" label="Save" onclick={CreateAccount}  class="slds-m-left_x-small"></lightning-button
</template>
```

Child Js

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import { createRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
const columns = [
   { label: 'Name', fieldName: 'name' , type:' text' , editable : true},
   { label: 'Phone', fieldName: 'phone', type: 'phone' , editable : true },
   { label: 'Description', fieldName: 'description', type: ' text' , editable : true},
   
];

const data = [
   {name : '', phone: '', description: ''},
   {name : '', phone: '', description: ''},
   {name : '', phone: '', description: ''},
   {name : '', phone: '', description: ''},
   {name : '', phone: '', description: ''},
];


export default class CreateAcc extends LightningElement {
   data = data;
   columns = columns;
   draftValues = [];
   accToSave = [];

   handleSave(event) {
      this.data = event.detail.draftValues;
   }
   
      CreateAccount(event){
         var selectedRecords =  this.template.querySelector("lightning-datatable").getSelectedRows();
         let fields ;
         let accObj;
         for(let i of this.data){
            if(selectedRecords == i && i.name != '' || i.name != null && selectedRecords != 0 ){
                    fields = {'Name' : i.name,
                              'Phone': i.phone,
                              'Description' : i.description};
                    accObj = {'apiName' : 'Account', fields};
                    console.log(accObj);
                    createRecord(accObj)
                    .then(response => {
                     const ev = new ShowToastEvent({
                                 title: 'Success',
                                 message: 'data is being downloaded',
                                 variant: 'success',
                                 
                             });
                             this.dispatchEvent(ev);
                             setTimeout(() => {
                              eval("$A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();");
                         }, 2000); 

                         const event = new CustomEvent("testevent",{
                           detail: [accObj]
                        });
                        this.dispatchEvent(event);
                          
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                       console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
                    })
            } else if(selectedRecords ==  i.name == '' || i.name == null){ 
               const evt = new ShowToastEvent({
                  title: 'Name is empty',
                  message: 'Name could not be empty',
                  variant: 'error',
              });
              this.dispatchEvent(evt)
              setTimeout(() => {
               eval("$A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();");
          }, 2000); 
            }
         }
      }
   }
```

Parent html

```
<template>
   <lightning-card title="Parent Component">
      <h1>Inside Parent Component</h1>
      <c-create-acc testevent={getdata}></c-create-acc>
      <c-show-new-acc-l-w-c></c-show-new-acc-l-w-c>
   </lightning-card>
</template>
```

Parent js

```
import { LightningElement,} from 'lwc';

export default class ParentOfTwoCmp extends LightningElement {
    dataFromChild ;

   getdata(event){
      this.dataFromChild = event.detail;
      console.log('It works');
   }
}
```

Comment: It is my first time here, sorry for my not correct paste the code

Comment: Not sure if the only problem here, but you should use ontestevent={getdata} in html when your event is named testevent.

Comment: maybe it is not good example what i need to do sorry
The main goal is i need to pass object to parent component(object which i create from my inline edit datatable)